# How do I lazy-load an "import { SelectedComponent } from {Library}"?

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading

I'm using React 18 with Vite and Ionic and I'm trying to lazy-load the IonDatetime component:

```
import { IonDatetime } from '@ionic/react';
const ControllerDatetime: React.FC<ControllerDatetimeProps> = ({
  control,
  label,
  name,
  clearErrors,
  disabled,
}: ControllerDatetimeProps) => {
  return (
    <Controller
      control={control}
      name={name}
      rules={{ required: true }}
      render={({
        field: { onChange, onBlur, value },
        fieldState: { invalid, isTouched },
      }) => (
        <IonDatetime>
          {label}
        </IonDatetime>
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

I can't figure out how to use lazy-loading here though.

I tried

`const IonDatetime = React.lazy(() => import { IonDatetime } from '@ionic/react')`

but it results in a syntax error.

I'm using lazy loading successfully to get default exports of my own components, but how do I lazy-load a specific component from a third-party library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `React.lazy` currently only supports default exports. If the module you want to import uses named exports, you can create an intermediate module that reexports it as the default. This ensures that tree shaking keeps working and that you don’t pull in unused components.
> ([Legacy React code-splitting docs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#named-exports))

```js
// IonDatetime.js
export { IonDatetime as default } from "@ionic/react";
```

```js
const IonDatetime = React.lazy(() => import("IonDatetime.js"))
```

Comment: This syntax works, but when I use it this way, it increases the bundle size by about 100 Kb because it imports **all** the components from `@ionic/react`, not just `IonDatetime` (it breaks tree-shaking).

Comment: @PatrickKenny Sorry, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, this loads the relevant component without increasing bundle size.  Unfortunately, vite is still bundling IonDatetime in the main bundle, but I'm guessing this is a vite issue then.  So I'm accepting this answer because it gives the correct syntax for lazy loading.

Comment: Hey @PatrickKenny. I have the same issue with Vite. Did you solve this issue ?

Comment: @ClémentCREUSAT No.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the intermediate module by doing this:

```js
const MyComponent = React.lazy(() =>
  import('./MyComponent').then((module) => ({ default: module.MyComponent }))
);
```

It's annoying to type, so I've personally started to use [react-lazily](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazily) instead, which will reduce the above to

```js
const { MyComponent } = lazily(() => import('./MyComponent'));
```